# S/Kademlia dynamic crypto puzzle

Tags: computer-networks

In S/Kademlia two crypto puzzles is used, one static and dynamic. The static is used to generate a key pair that makes an eclipse attack difficult to achieve, the dynamic to make Sybil attacks harder.

[image: crypto puzzles]

In the dynamic, I am very confused about the *x* which is found, since I can’t find any evidence for this ever being used again in the system, is it send along in a signature or what is it used to?

I do not think the [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=079445BBCC01CF4C937E58A5260BDC1B?doi=10.1.1.68.4986&rep=rep1&type=pdf) mentions any use of it, I at least have not been able to find it, why I ask here for the use of *x*.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the solution to the cryptopuzzle.  The goal is to find $x$ that makes $P$ satisfy the criterion; once you've found such an $x$, you can verify that it is a valid solution (and so can anyone else).

Comment: I have come to terms with, that the $x$ is send along with any message, so other peers can validate that the puzzle was solved